# Finding averages using two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that I wish to use:

```
dictionary1 = {'Reece': 2, 'Harry': 3, 'Jack': 3, 'Sam': 3, 'Dom': 3}
dictionary2 = {'Reece': 1, 'Harry': 14, 'Jack': 8, 'Sam': 16, 'Dom': 5}
```

I wish to divide each value in dictionary2 by the value in dictionary1, and print this out.
This would print something like:

> Reece:0.5
>
> Harry:4.66

I'm currently trying to print and round these by using this code, which is erroring:

```
for b in dictionary2
            print('{}: {} '.format(b[0], round(b[1]/dictionary1[1], 2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using keys

```
In [74]: {k: round(float(dictionary2[k])/dictionary1[k],2) for k in dictionary2}
Out[74]: {'Dom': 1.67, 'Harry': 4.67, 'Jack': 2.67, 'Reece': 0.5, 'Sam': 5.33}
```

Or use `items` as @JuniorCompressor pointed out

```
In [75]: {k: round(float(v)/dictionary1[k], 2) for k, v in dictionary2.items()} 
Out[75]: {'Dom': 1.67, 'Harry': 4.67, 'Jack': 2.67, 'Reece': 0.5, 'Sam': 5.33}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = {item:round(dictionary2.get(item)/dictionary1.get(item), 2) for item in dictionary1}
```

`results`:

> {'Reece': 0.5, 'Harry': 4.67, 'Sam': 5.33, 'Dom': 1.67, 'Jack': 2.67}

```
print(*(': '.join([item, str(results.get(item))]) for item in results), sep='\n')
```

> Reece: 0.5
>
> Harry: 4.67
>
> Sam: 5.33
>
> Dom: 1.67
>
> Jack: 2.67

Comment: You may want to use `float(dictionary2.get(item))` as by default python2 does int division.

Comment: Good to note for those using Python 2, but the question did specify Python 3, so it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

hovewer the logic is almost same with solutions above, you can intuitively catch what is happening. you can format floats for your need when printing or storing

```
>>> for k1 in dictionary2.keys():
...     for k2 in dictionary1.keys():
...             if k1 == k2:
...                     print k1, float(dictionary2[k1])/dictionary1[k2]
```

the below one is more simple - so python interpeteter will not overloaded

```
>>> for k in dictionary2.keys():
...     print k, float(dictionary2[k])/dictionary1[k]
```